# Facebook Register As Developer - Button broken?

Tags: facebook

No idea what I am supposed to be doing here.

My game is scheduled to be released end of the week and the last thing to put in is Facebook Login, but when I click "Register as Developer" it just blinks a window quickly.

I had a look through the bugs, nothing seems to be posted. Is this on my end? I have tried Chrome and IE, running windows 8.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248826/facebook-cant-register-as-developer This seems to be a bugs from Facebook.

Comment: Damn that was 9 hours ago, guess my game will be delayed at this rate...lol, thanks

Comment: The windows asked me for password confirmation then did nothing after I confirmed. Then it just goes back to blinking.

Comment: Yeah this is bad, really sucks :( I see no message from facebook (unless I can't because I am not a dev)